# Users keep re-activating Office 365 with Remote Desktop Server Farm

Tags: windows-server-2016, microsoft-office-365, remote-desktop-services

We are running a farm of three Remote Desktop hosts with Office installed.
This being a farm, users get randomly assigned to an arbitrary member at different logins.
Clearly, the various farm members should not count against the 5 PC per user limit (in particular, as the farm may soon grow to more than 5 members) and moreover the user experience should be seamless without repeated activation requests.

Per GPO, the setting `Microsoft Office 2016 (Host) / Licensing Settings / Use shared computer activation` is activated.
Also, its sibling setting "set storage for license token with shared computer activation" is activated with value `%appdata%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Licensing`.
(As the latter is mentioned, we also use folder redirection of AppData(Roaming) to  `\\foo\bar$\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming`)

We encounter the following (related?) problems:

a) Users very often have to (re-)activate Office. Not every user every day, but often enough that we get numerous support calls every morning

b) Contrary to what we expect, the activation dialog does not even have the username pre-filled.

Once we manually go through the activation, everything works fine, so there is no *real* licensing problem. However, this has to be possible without that hassle - and as far as I can tell, this should already be the case with the above settings.

Comment: Do you have installed Office 365 **Pro Plus**?

Comment: @Daniel Yes - sorry for not mentioning

Comment: @Daniel Duh - I checked again: The assigned  **licences** are ProPlus, but apparently the software **installed** is not (Under "Acount", Word only says "Product Information - Office" but not "Subscription product"). -- Thank you for pointing to the obvious I overlooked

Comment: @Daniel This is vexing me - given that form within a session, the software showed as **non** 365 (i..e, as non-subscription), I wanted to use some downtime tonight to correct the wrong installation - only to find that the software I was going to uninstall is called "Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus - de-de". So we are back to square one: The software installed really *is* Office 365 **Pro Plus**